# C#: List sorting different than leetCode answer. How to get the answer they want?

Tags: c#

Below code:

```
List<string> tmpstring = new List<string>() { "john_newyork@mail.com", "john00@mail.com", "johnsmith@mail.com" };
tmpstring.Sort();
Console.WriteLine($"{tmpstring[0]} {tmpstring[1]} {tmpstring[2]}");
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019, and the output I got was:

```
john_newyork@mail.com john00@mail.com johnsmith@mail.com
```

leetcode said that was the wrong answer, and it should be:

```
john00@mail.com john_newyork@mail.com johnsmith@mail.com
```

How could I change the "Sort" function to get that answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a Comparer, in this case, an ordinal comparer:

```cs
List<string> tmpstring = new List<string>() { "john_newyork@mail.com", "john00@mail.com", "johnsmith@mail.com" };
tmpstring.Sort(string.CompareOrdinal);
Console.WriteLine($"{tmpstring[0]} {tmpstring[1]} {tmpstring[2]}");
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareordinal?view=net-5.0)